# Does ScripttagsManager handle routing for Script Tags in ShopifyApp gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app

I have a ScriptTag that I load into the Shopify store using the shopify_app initializer within my app like this:

```
ShopifyApp.configure do |config|
  config.application_name = "My App"
  config.api_key = THE_KEY
  config.secret = THE_SECRET
  config.scope = "read_script_tags, write_script_tags"
  config.embedded_app = true
  config.scripttags = [{event: 'onload', src: 'https://theappname.herokuapp.com/scripts/myscript.js'}]
end
```

Store-side I get this message in the console:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://theappname.herokuapp.com/scripts/myscript.js?shop=theshopname.myshopify.com”.
```

In the app logs I get this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/scripts/myscript.js")
```

Does ScripttagsManager not handle routing for the script tag in the same way that WebhooksManager does?

Do the routes have to be created manually for each script tag?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You do need to make a route. You do need to provide the code for the src. Makes sense right?